# Why there isn't any popular php server?

Tags: php, persistent

I'm not asking this to start a troll, but it starts with an observation.
Every programming languages have their own server that increase their performances.

Ruby have [Mongrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongrel_%28web_server%29), [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/). Python have many frameworks with integrated servers (ready for production or not), like in [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), etc. And don't mention java!

For now, PHP code is served via servers like Apache or NGinx but what I mean is like a "**pre-environment**":
If we take example on Tornado Web Server, the idea could be used, for example, to load an entire "meta" framework when the server starts : **DB connection created once and only once**, the URL interpreter with all the url regular expression, the core framework, loaded only once in order to save the server's cpu.
Then, the "executed regarding the request" code would be executed at the request.

**The core reason of this idea is to keep the PHP code loaded once,** in order to reduce the server load for every request and improve the response time.

Of course, many (if not all) actual PHP could wouldn't work and a garbage collector equivalent would be necessary to unload all the unused code.

Writing it in PHP is the base idea since it would be (kind of) linked to the loaded component (a web framework) but the server could be written in any other language. The principal purpose being to load the whole PHP code only one time, when the server starts.

Do you find any good reason to not do it? Am I forgot something? Maybe there is already something equivalent I wasn't aware about?

Comment: The Apache2 SAPI PHP module already does that. The Zend Engine is only loaded on server start, not on each page load.

Comment: I thought `Apache + PHP + MySQL` is quite popular. :D

Comment: Do you mean something like http://wiki.php.net/rfc/builtinwebserver?

Comment: Nginx + FastCGI PHP, the web claims this is the fastest

Comment: Apache (+PHP+MySQL) load the PHP code at every request. That the anti-purpose of my question. I'll take a look at the SAPI module. @Gordon : Yes, exactly! Thanks

Comment: I was more thinking about a already known frontend server (like apache) with proxy to a php cluster server manager.

Comment: cx42net, are you talking about compiling the PHP code, sort of like ASP creates a .dll of the code for its web apps? If so, there are a few projects that do this, perhaps one of the more popular ones is `Hip Hop for PHP`

Comment: OP is talking about a webserver completely written in PHP.

Comment: cx42net, I would probably mark this as a community wiki, given there is not "true" answer, but it would be interesting topic to have discussed.

Comment: @sexyprout : What is OP? @Brad : Thanks. (I'll update my post to try to explain more since a lot of people seems to believe I forgot about apache ;))

Comment: @cx42net "Original poster"--you.

Comment: @Brad : If you want to mark this as a community wiki, please do so. I'm really interested to know more about this situation :)